# What is the meaning of 结束退场时 in 却常常忽视结束退场时的准备?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

比如说为了一场戏剧演出，我们会投入很多时间，准备服装、化妆、道具、舞台美术，以创造良好的效果，争取给观众留下一个好的印象，却常常忽视结束退场时的准备。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5 section 17.

What is the meaning of 结束退场时? end leaving the theater time?

Why do I think that one of them is unneeded?

Don't the following sentences make the same sense?

却常常忽视结束时的准备

却常常忽视退场时的准备

Especially the first (with or without 时) doesn't make the same sense as the initial clause?

Comment: I think you can refer to this answer. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/52304/9346

Answer (score 1):

Let's translate the partial sentence: "..., 却常常忽视结束退场时的准备."

- yet/but often neglect the preparation for **getting off the stage at the end** (of the show).

Now, let's try the sentences in your thought:

- yet/but often neglect the preparation for the **closing/end**. [Q: Prepare for what?]
- yet/but often neglect the preparation for **getting off/leaving the stage**. {Q: Prepare for leaving the stage at when?]

It is now clear that only the original fits the form of "preparation for **what**, at **when**." - the essence of a good sentence.

Answer (score 0):

结束退场 can be considered as 演出结束(大家)退场.

If you remove one of them, the meaning will be different. The original phrase includes the sense of 演出结束 and (大家)退场.

Answer (score 0):

The term 结束退场 is a combined phrase of 结束 and 退场 and means "to end (the show/concert/event...) and leave the stage". The former refers to the event ending generally, the latter more specifically points to the actors. Together, they are a 4-character-phrase

It contains more information than the two alternatives you offer. The alternatives do carry the same general meaning and are grammatically correct, however do not convey the exact same meaning/image. Neither do they have the same flow to it as the original; for me (speaking as a native), reading the original feels slightly more "formal" (uncolloquial) and linguistically expressive. Also note that the latter two characters add some context to the clause, specifying that it was a performance (which was albeit already clear from the previous clauses, but nevertheless a nice touch).