# The function of 慢行 in 减速慢行

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

I understand that the phrase 减速慢行  simply means "slow down", but I'm not sure why 慢行 is there, since 减速 solely can (at least in my non-native logic) express the idea of "slowing down".

What is grammatical relationship between "减速" and 慢行?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

减速 = **decelerate** --> go from 120 km/h to 100 km/h is a slowdown but it doesn't mean you are traveling at a low speed

慢行 = **traveling at a low speed** -->following the speed limit, e.g. 10 km/h

减速慢行 = slow down and maintain a low speed

> What is the grammatical relationship between "减速" and 慢行?

减速 and 慢行 are two verbs one after another, first slow down then maintain at a low speed. It is similar to 對號入座，棄械投降 (先對號後入座; 先棄械後投降)

Answer (score 1):

What is the grammatical relationship between "减速" and 慢行?

They are repetitions or overloads.

In Chinese literature, there are a lot of these kinds of "repetitions". In many cases, it is difficult to tell whether they are truly repeating one another, or they are two things but have very similar meanings. Nevertheless, the grammar is OK and the indication is clear.

The purpose of intentionally using the repetitions is to have an aesthetic and confrontative effect, especially in poems, lyrics, and four-character idioms.

For example,

他 原来 是 一个 有 雄心壮志 的 青年人. Before he was an ambitious young man.

现在，他 搬到 了 乡下，过着 清心寡欲 的 生活. Now, he moved to the countryside and lives an ascetic lifestyle.

很多 人 下岗 失业 了。(Many people lost their jobs and became unemployed).

她 高高兴兴 地 回家了。(She went home cheerfully).

他 慢慢腾腾 地 走着. (He walks slowly).

Comment: not quite like 雄心壮志 or 清心寡欲; 减速慢行 are two commands one after another, first slow down then maintain at a low speed. It is similar to 對號入座，棄械投降 (先對號後入座; 先棄械後投降)

Comment: @TangHo Strictly speaking, the sequence between "减速" and 慢行 is not significant enough to put this phrase 减速慢行 into the same category with 對號入座. Also it is valuable for this answer to introduce the idea of repetitions in Chinese.

Comment: I didn't put them in the same category, I was saying the relationship between 减速 and 慢行 is the same as the relationship between 對號 and 入座 -- "two verbs one after another"

Answer (score 0):

减速(reduce speed)慢(slow)行(travel/drive).

减速慢行 - "Reduce speed. Travel/Drive slow(ly)."